# Wifi adapter seems gone... kinda

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless

Ok so I rebooted my computer, and something is different... My Wifi connect panel is gone! Seems like I do not have a wifi adaptar anymore!

[image]

Weird thing is that using lshw **does detect** the adaptar...

```
➜ lshw -C network                            
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3400000-a3407fff memory:a3200000-a33fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 40:b0:76:de:79:9a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.178.48 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 memory:a3500000-a351ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

What is going on?!

**UPDATE**

```
➜ sudo dkms build bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch 0002-Makefile.patch...patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 succeeded at 113 with fuzz 1.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 132 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).

applying patch 0003-Make-up-for-missing-init_MUTEX.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 111 with fuzz 2 (offset 12 lines).

applying patch 0010-change-the-network-interface-name-from-eth-to-wlan.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 221 (offset -14 lines).

applying patch 0013-gcc.patch...patching file Makefile

applying patch 0019-broadcom-sta-6.30.223.248-3.18-null-pointer-fix.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2169 (offset 12 lines).

applying patch 0020-add-support-for-linux-4.3.patch...patching file src/shared/linux_osl.c

applying patch 0021-add-support-for-Linux-4.7.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c

applying patch 0022-add-support-for-Linux-4.8.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2391 (offset 3 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 2501 (offset 3 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 2933 (offset 9 lines).

applying patch 0023-add-support-for-Linux-4.11.patch...patching file src/include/linuxver.h
patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2919 (offset 4 lines).

applying patch 0024-add-support-for-Linux-4.12.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 55 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 472 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 2371 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 2388 (offset 5 lines).

applying patch 0025-add-support-for-Linux-4.14.patch...patching file src/shared/linux_osl.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1080 (offset 4 lines).

applying patch 0026-add-support-for-Linux-4.15.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
Hunk #2 succeeded at 2306 (offset 4 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 2368 (offset 4 lines).


Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=5.3.0-20-generic -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-20-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.3.0-20-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
```

Could it be that the kernel 5.3.0-20 broke the drivers??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 with a 5.3 kernel, you will need to do in terminal

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/b/broadcom-sta/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-11_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-11_all.deb
```

Then reboot

Comment: You know it worked well ;)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Can you guide me for alternative ways ?

Answer (score 0):

your problem could be related to several things.

**1) Secure boot**

Have you check that the secure boot option is disabled in the BIOS  (it could prevent from Broadcom wireless card to be recognized).

**2) rfkill**

Have you check the rfkill list to see if anything on the hardware or software is preventing you to use your wireless card ? Use this command `rfkill list`

**3) Re-installing the driver `bcmwl-kernel-source`**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bmcwl-kernel-source
```

I'm not sure it will solve your problem but at least it will remove some options of the list.
As an alternative, you can find maybe some info here: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: I reinstalled the driver already... As far as my suspicious go... I think it a kernel problem

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your update. If it is related to the kernel, a downgrade of the kernel should be informative. Have you upgrade the kernel recently (before loosing the wifi) ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but it could have happened without me noticing. I tried with 5.3.0.0-19 and it did not solve it. I tried it with 5.0.0 and it didnt even detect my mouse, so... yeah...

Comment: Damned ! ... I'm out of ideas ... sorry for that